# Understanding Rails config.assets - when assets are not enabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

Hopefully this is a really simple question for someone…

If…

`rails.config.assets.enabled = false`

…does that mean that rails will ignore any other configuration settings for `config.assets`?

For example,

`config.assets.debug = true` etc

I'm fairly sure this isn't doing anything, but can't be 100% sure.

Comment: which version of rails are you using?

Comment: version 6.0 currently

Answer (score 0):

It seems this setting was removed. Check out the following threads:

- https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/44525
- https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/15

Basically, if you want to fully disable the Rails Asset Pipeline you should remove the `sprockets-rails` gem.

Comment: Thanks for these links. Although helpful, they have only added to my confusion! 
The `sprockets-rails` gem is a dependency of `rails` (I think), so I can't fully remove it. It's not in the `Gemfile` but appears in the `Gemfile.lock`.

Comment: It depends on the Rails version. Since 7+, is not a direct dependency anymore: https://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions/7.0.0/dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You are disabling asset pipeline in this line application.rb

```
rails.config.assets.enabled = false
```

So expectation now is all asset related configuration will not change anything. Same applied to

> config.assets.debug = true

Comment: Yes, that is my expectation too. But I can't find anywhere to confirm this…